# Calling a function in PageBase from a MasterPage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, master-pages

I have a PageBase page in App_Code. In it is a function called LoadContext().

I have a master page that inherits from System.Web.UI.MasterPage.  All the pages on my site use this MasterPage and inherit from the PageBase class.

An example is: public partial class Notifications : PageBase

How do I call the LoadContext() function from my MasterPage.master.cs file?

Comment: How does it affect the MasterPage controls or rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you probably want this:

`(this.Page as PageBase).LoadContext()`